# Ban a variable from a list with a "ban" list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I ban a variable from a list without removing it from that list by adding the variable to a list of "banned" variable?

I wish to be able to type in a string. That string is compared to the file names in a folder. If there is a match, the file is read. If I type this same string again, the file should not be read again. There for I want to have a list of "banned" string that is checked whilst typing to avoid the file to be read again.

I have tried a few ways but not getting there. Below is an example of my last attempt.

What would be the best way?

```
public class test 
{

 string scl= "test3";

 List <string> lsf,lso;

 void Start () 
 {
  lsf=//file names 
   new List<string>();

  lso=//files open 
   new List<string>();

  lsf.Add("test0");
  lsf.Add("test1");
  lsf.Add("test2");
  lsf.Add("test3");
  lsf.Add("test4");

  lso.Add("idhtk49fngo");//random string        
 }

void Update () 
{
 if
 (
  Input.GetKeyDown("a")
 )
 {
  for
  (
   int i=0;
   i<lsf.Count;
   i++
  )
  {
   if(lsf[i]==scl)
   {
    Debug.Log
    (i+" is read");

    for
    (
     int j=0;
     j<lso.Count;
     j++
    )
    {

     //how can i avoid reading
     //lsf[3] here the second time
     //"a" is pressed (by having "test3" 
     //added to a "ban" list (lso) )

     if(scl!=lso[j])
     {

      lso.Add(lsf[i]);

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: "Ban" is the wrong term. "AlreadyChecked" is the right one. At it's score, you need a list (AlreadyChecked) and contains check on any input before you run it through the folder itterator. Note that you might run into issue with excact spelling and normalisation, but with Windows Filename Search that is part of the mechanic anyway.

Comment: Your question is a borderline case example for a "XY" problem. The X you want to solve is "do not touch the same file/folder twice". The Y you came up with was a "ban list" on the inputs. There might actually be a better solution if you ask for teh X, rather then for help with your choosen Y.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest such way:

```
public static List<string> openedFiles = new List<string>();
public static string ReadFileAndAddToOpenedList(string path)
{
    if (openedFiles.Contains(path))
        throw new Exception("File already opened");
        // Instead of throwing exception you could for example just log this or do something else, like:
        // Consolle.WriteLine("File already opened");
    else
    {
        openedFiles.Add(path);
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
}
```

The idea is - on every file read, add file to list, so you can check every time you try read file, if it was already read (or opened). If it is, throw exception (or do something else). Else read a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of making it a string list use your own class

```c#
public class MyFile
{
    public string Name;
    public bool isOpen;

    public MyFile(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        isOpen = false;
    }
}

List<MyFile> lsf = new List<MyFile>()
{
    new MyFile("test0"),
    new MyFile("test1"),
    new MyFile("test2"),
    new MyFile("test3"),
    new MyFile("test4")
};
```

Than when you read the file set `isOpen` to true

```c#
MyFile[someIndex].isOpen = true;
```

and later you can check this

```c#
// E.g. skip in a loop
if(MyFile[someIndex]) continue;
```

You could than also use `Linq` in order to get a list of only unread files:

```c#
var unreadFiles = lsf.Select(f => f.Name).Where(file => !file.isOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael’s answer is the way to go here but it can be improved using the more appropriate collection available to keep track of opened files; if you want uniqueness use a set, not a list:

```
 HashSet<string> openedFiles = new HashSet<string>();

 public static bool TryFirstRead(
     string path,
     out string result)
 {
     if (openedFiles.Add(path))
     {
          result = File.ReadAllText(path);
          return true;
     }

     result = null;
     return false;
 }
```

Also, I’d avoid throwing [vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). Give the consumer a friendly way to know if the file was read or not, don’t make them end up having to use exceptions as a flow control mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand although if you want to replace a value from another list.
You can use the list index to create a new list with the values which you removed.
`String list1 = {"hi", "hello", "World"};
String list2 = {"bye", "goodbye", "World"};
List1[1] = list2[1];`